# Perl split() without removing delimiter

Tags: perl, split, declaration, tokenize

I'm trying to parse c functions declarations. I want to get arrays of tokens from string.
so i use split:

```
$function = "int func1(  int *   , const   float, const char[])"
print split(/(\(|\)|\*|[|]|,|\ )/, $function);
```

it returns array of this

```
["int" "func1", "(", "int", "*", ",", "const", "float", ",", "const", "char[]", ")"]
```

which is basicly correct, but i need not to remove the spaces. So I expected something like this

```
["int " "func1", "(  ", "int ", "*   ", ", ", "const   ", "float", ", ", "const ", "char[]", ")"]
```

Have I any option? (instead of write my own lexical parser)

Comment: Have you looked at CPAN? You almost certainly don't need to write your own, but writing your own naively using `split` seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters, it doesn't remove the spaces. They are being returned.

```
'int',' ','func1','(','',' ','',' ','int',' ','','*','',' ','',' ','',' ','',',','',' ','const',' ','',' ','',' ','float',',','',' ','const',' ','char[]',')'
```

They are simply being returned in as their own "token", along with many empty strings.

The first arg to `split` should match what separates the tokens, but that's obviously not what you provided. Since no characters actually separate the tokens, it would have to be something that matches zero characters. That means lookahead and/or lookbehinds needs to be used.

```
split /(?=[()*|,])|(?<=[ ()*,])(?! )/
```

will give the following (which is exactly what you asked for):

```
'int ',
'func1',
'(  ',
'int ',
'*   ',
', ',
'const   ',
'float',
', ',
'const ',
'char[]',
')'
```

Comment: Probably, its not perfect, if i try this: "int * (* func3          ( void ** (*) (int *, char **(*)(char *, char **))))(const int (*)[10])". It returns this http://prntscr.com/u3vvn which is very close to solution. Can you please write the re little bit better? anyway thanks a lot

Comment: @l0v3, Fixed it. It's the same you came up with.

Answer (score 3):

Did you checked these?

There are several existsing way to parse C source in Perl.

http://search.cpan.org/~dconway/Parse-RecDescent/demo/demo_another_Cgrammar.pl

http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=746341

From example:

```
use GCC::TranslationUnit;

  # echo '#include <stdio.h>' > stdio.c
  # gcc -fdump-translation-unit -c stdio.c
  $node = GCC::TranslationUnit::Parser->parsefile('stdio.c.tu')->root;

  # list every function/variable name
  while($node) {
    if($node->isa('GCC::Node::function_decl') or
       $node->isa('GCC::Node::var_decl')) {
      printf "%s declared in %s\n",
        $node->name->identifier, $node->source;
    }
  } continue {
    $node = $node->chain;
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately its a school project and this libs should help me too much :/